# How do I use my own .Net library on Linux from Ruby?

Tags: .net, ruby, linux, mono, interop

I made a .Net library which works in mono 2.10.
Is there a way to make this library accessible from Ruby or PHP on a Linux machine?

On windows this is possible with COM interop/IronRuby, but is there a way on Linux/Unix?

Comment: You could build IronRuby on Mono if you want, but it might be a bit troublesome.

Comment: I would actually prefer the regular ruby if possible

Comment: I don't think a CLR bridge for Linux exists. You best bet is to create some kind of Mono web service which you can access from Ruby.

Comment: it may require a bit of work but if i remember correctly you can use COM objects in linux with wine, would you be able to create a COM object from ruby using wine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a web service as suggested by Niklas B
This was a nice solution for what I needed.